# Sql Server 2008 radius search using spatial features

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial-query

I have looked at many SO questions similar to mine but I cannot seem to get anything to work in my specific case. I have an implementation of radius based searching that works okay using a zip code and a radius, but the accuracy is somewhat low, since people can live at the edges of their zip codes and it limits the applications reach to only places with zip codes. So what I am trying to do is use the latitude and longitude of the users location and, using sql server spatial features, return a list of ids from my Locations table that have a Latitude and Longitude within a user defined radius. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Id FROM Location WHERE (GetDistanceBetween(39.0997, 94.5783, Latitude,     
Longitude)<=5)
```

And GetDistanceBetween defined as such:

```
 FUNCTION [GetDistanceBetween]
(
@Lat1 float,
@Long1 float,
@Lat2 float,
@Long2 float
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @RetVal float;
DECLARE @startPoint geography;
DECLARE @endPoint geography;
SET @startPoint = geography::Point(@Lat1, @Long1, 4326)
SET @endPoint = geography::Point(@Lat2, @Long2, 4326)
SET @RetVal = (SELECT @startPoint.STDistance(@endPoint) / 3959 );


RETURN @RetVal;


END
```

The Location table contains three columns, Latitude, Longitude and Id. Each Location row belongs to another table Address that I need information out of. What I am trying to do in a stored procedure then is this:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGeoObjectsInRange](
@startLat as float (10),
@startLong as float(10), 
@range  as numeric (15) 
)

AS
BEGIN


Select * from dbo.Address WHERE geolocation_id in (SELECT Id from Location          
WHERE GetDistanceBetween(@startLat, @startLong, Latitude, Longitude)<=@range)
RETURN
END
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the result of the GetDistanceBetween calls to another select. This currently returns no results while my other way returns 39 results. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? I am not really a database guy but being to only developer on a project has forced me to learn my way around them.
If it matters I am calling the stored procedure from a C# MVC3 application using NHibernate.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It turns out nothing is wrong with the query above. It works exactly as expected and when you put in the correct inputs it event returns the correct results. Took writing some test queries to figure out the problem though.